# React renders only on first setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use chat-ui-kit-react to populate as MessageList with messages I get from another function:

Component to render Chat:

```js
export default function Chat() {
    const msgListRef = useRef();
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([])
    
    function handleHistory(response) {
        if (!response?.length) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (response.length > history?.length) {
            msgListRef.current.scrollToBottom('smooth');
        }

        setHistory(response);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        handleHistory(getTalkHistory().talkhistory)
        
        setInterval(() => {
            handleHistory(getTalkHistory().talkhistory)
        }, 5000)
    }, [])
    
    return <main>
    <MessageList style={{ display: "flex" }} ref={ msgListRef }>
      <Message model={{
        message: 'Hello!',
        position: 'single',
        direction: 'incoming',
      }} />
      { history?.length ? <MessageSeparator content={history[0].time.toLocaleString()} /> : null }
      { history.map(message => <Message model={{
        message: converter.makeHtml(message.text),
        position: 'single',
        direction: message.direction,
        }} /> )}
     
      {hljs.highlightAll()}
    </MessageList>
  </main>
```

On load it will display the "Hello!" and the first time getTalkHistory returns something that is not empty (ie after it has been populated through other means), it will re-render and correctly display any messages sent/received by the time setState is called. If I increase the interval time higher, it will display more messages (if any have been sent or received). It does not matter how long the app has been running before getTalkHistory returns something for the first time, it will always work the first time, but not after.

However, afterwards it never rerenders again. No matter how many messages are being added and returned by getTalkHistory, it never updates again :/

getTalkHistory returns Chatdata as an array. If I console.log it is correctly updated at all times:

[image]

If I console.log the history.map it looks like this on the first time it renders:
[image]

However the console.log only fires two times, one time when getTalkHistory first returns something and then on the next interval (ie 5 seconds later). The second console.log can show additional messages that have been generated since, but hose messages are never rendered and the map console.log never fires again afterwards. console.log(getTalkHistory())  will fire correctly inside the setInterval and always return all messages though. So the state keeps getting updated, it just doesn't render :/

Comment: "it will always work the first time, but not after" let me guess, you keep an array `talkhistory` and `push()` new items into it over time, right? Ans about that construct with `setInterval`, turn `getTalkHistory` into a store that [useSyncExternalStore](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore) can subscribe to.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I'm doing:

`talkhistory.push({ text: message, time: new Date(), direction })`

Comment: Then the topic at hand is "mutation". the array that you pass to `setHistory` is always the same *(even if it's content changed)* therefore the state didn't change, so no reason for a rerender. Don't `push` items to `talkhistory` concat them `talkhistory = talkhistory.concat(newItems)` or `talkhistory = [...talkhistory, ...newItems];`

Comment: Ayyo well that was a few hours I could have saved myself, thanks a lot lol. It works like this (I have two function that manipulate talkhistory: one that adds a new message and one that updates an existing one because text is delivered from another service as messages).  

`talkhistory.push({ text: message, time: new Date(), direction })`  
`talkhistory = [...talkhistory]`  
  
and  
  
`talkhistory[talkhistory.length - 1].text = message`  
`talkhistory = [...talkhistory]`  
  
works, thanks a ton!